# How to install external USB Wi-Fi adapter driver in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, usb, drivers

I am using Kali Linux on my laptop and my laptop's internal Wi-Fi adapter is not working, so I have an external USB adapter. Now after the installation I plug my Wi-Fi adapter and Linux is not showing it and I also don't know how to install its driver so help me what should I do in this situation.

Driver folder--
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tgp5jaelqzvKw39nPp564i9Vzwl6tFfH

External Wi-Fi adapter--
(exabyte )Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188FTV 802.11b/g/n 1T1R 2.4G WLAN Adapter

Comment: What is lsusb showing when it's plugged in?

Comment: lsusb is showing but in top right wifi section it does not show wifi adapter

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tgp5jaelqzvKw39nPp564i9Vzwl6tFfH               from this link u have access to have driver folder comes with wifi adapter can u tell me which file i should use and how to install it

Answer (score 1):

Alright. Better strap in, because it's going to be a long one:

1. Open your terminal and start working.
2. Run `lsusb -v`, which should give you an output similar to this:

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188FTV
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

3. Since the adapter is an USB adapter, you run `dmesg | grep usbcore` as root, which should give you an output similar to this `usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8188`.
4. Check if the wireless interface has been created using `ip link`. If the adapter has been created the name of the adapter should start with a 'w' (e.g. `wlan0`; `wlp2s0`).
5. Use the `ip link set [YOUR INTERFACE] up` command to bring up your interface (e.g. `ip link set wlan0 up`. If you get an error message, please provide it by commenting the answer I'm providing you.
6. Check the kernel messages if the firmware is being loaded with `dmesg | grep firmware`, which should yield something like this:

```
[   7.148259] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 39.30.4.1 build 35138 op_mode iwldvm
```

7. If there is no erroneous output to the command in step 6, use `dmesg | grep [FIRMWARE]` (in the case of step 6, it was `iwlwifi`. Again, yours may be different).
8. If the kernel module was loaded properly, you can proceed to the next step in the [Arch wiki (#Utilities)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration/Wireless#Utilities)

I checked the support from the [Kernel wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers) and I suspect that your device may not be supported.

Again, I suggest following the [Arch wiki - Wireless network configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration/Wireless), which provides a fantastic way to solve your issue. This goes for general Linux issues as well. It is very easy to follow and it is aimed at beginners and proficient users alike.

Comment: Answers should be self-contained. If the link goes bad in the future, this answer will become useless. Please include essential parts of the linked resource in your answer, then cite the link as a source.

Comment: I see. It's quite the chapter though, with a lot of steps and a lot of extra steps/explanations. So that's the practice on the site? Like, adding the steps and link to source?

Comment: This site, and all other sites in the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) network, are basically built to become the ultimate, lasting resources for their particular domain. Link-only answers pose a problem in this model, because rather than provide useful guidance immediately they point users to a third party which may not be as reliable. Providing useful links is welcome of course, but unless you can frame it as a self-contained solution, you should post them as comments.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the heads-up. I have now updated my answer to, at least, check if the modules and firmware are properly loaded.

Answer (score 0):

## ip link set wlan0 up                                                                                                                                          1 ⨯

RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).